# magento product collection by name

Tags: php, magento, search

```
  <?php
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load();

$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   **echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';**//getting this only
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}

?>
```

I am trying to get product collection based on product name but I get only product URL.  I am trying get other attributes like name. My purpose is to create a search page.

Comment: The problem is that you loaded your collection before adding the filters. Just remove the ->load() from getCollection().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this might help :

```
$searchstring = 'Slim fit';
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection() 
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$searchstring.'%'));

foreach ($productCollection as $_product){

            echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select those attributes.

```
        $needle= $_GET["singleid"];         
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
                array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
                array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
                array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
        ));
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name', 'entity_id', 'price');
        foreach ($collection as $_product){

            echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';//getting this only
            echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';

        }
```

Check [here](http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-product-collection-bible) for more information

Comment: this returns a null value am i need to add any extra code

Comment: Null value means , empty? I just checked this code it is giving all the information?

Comment: yes empty actually i refered this link
[check](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11082/filtering-results-using-like)

Comment: i do not have thorough knowledge in magento, am i need to add helper codes?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try some thing like

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Some Name');
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name', 'some name xyz');

It may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$searchstring  = 'abc'  // search string 
$product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$searchstring.'%'))
              ->load();

 foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
     $ids[] = $product->getId();
 }
//return array of product ids
```